# Understanding the ngRepeat 'track by' expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having difficulties understanding how the **track by** expression of ng-repeat in angularjs works. The documentation is very scarce: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Can you explain what the difference between those two snippets of code is in terms of **databinding** and other relevant aspects?

with: `track by $index`

```html
<!--names is an array-->
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in names track by $index">
  <input ng-model="value[key]">                         
</div>
```

without (same output)

```html
<!--names is an array-->
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in names">
   <input ng-model="value[key]">                         
</div>
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can `track by $index` if your data source has duplicate identifiers

e.g.: `$scope.dataSource: [{id:1,name:'one'}, {id:1,name:'one too'}, {id:2,name:'two'}]`

You can't iterate this collection while using 'id' as identifier (duplicate id:1).

**WON'T WORK:**

```
<element ng-repeat="item.id as item.name for item in dataSource">
  // something with item ...
</element>
```

but you can, if using `track by $index`:

```
<element ng-repeat="item in dataSource track by $index">
  // something with item ...
</element>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But surely duplicate identifiers aren't the only use-case. Also I'd like to know what's happening 'under the hood'.

Comment: well, that's easy: just have a look at the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L3), it's all open source ;)

Comment: This question is old but I still think this might help understand much better  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm short version of the explanation here  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: One more thing to take into account is that if you can use track by key, you will get better performance (blog.500tech.com/is-reactjs-fast ). This feature allows you to associate a JavaScript object with an ngRepeat DOM (Document Object Model) node using a unique identifier. With this association in place, AngularJS will not $destroy and re-create DOM nodes unnecessarily. This can have a huge performance and user experience benefit (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm).

Comment: I have a list of 700 odd items. Render time went from 4 seconds to 100ms. Track by should be used for all ngRepeat's based on data sourced from rest.

Comment: I am able to use `$index` without using track by. How?

Comment: @AstitvaSrivastava $index is property of the ngRepeat directive. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
Adding `track by $index` just forces ngRepeat to use $index as identifier.

Comment: @nilsK Thanks. I got it!

Comment: `<element ng-repeat="item.id as item.name for item in dataSource">` - This doesn't work even if the values in "dataSource" aren't dups it just throws a syntax error..

Comment: @BornToCode thats why i wrote 'WON'T WORK' in uppercase and bold above the text ^^ please use the second example with track by $index

Comment: Yes but the fact that it doesn't work doesn't illustrate your point. It doesn't work because of corrupted syntax, not because of dups.

Comment: Just an example of why this might matter regarding avoiding errors: https://jsfiddle.net/8gy4tnrL/6/

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 This post and answer is from 2014. AngularJs is deprecated.

Comment: @nilsK angularJs is still used by entire products. So it is relevant to those; unfortunate, nonetheless. It's why I found myself here.

Answer (score 65):

*a short summary:*

`track by` is used in order to link your data with the DOM generation (and mainly re-generation) made by ng-repeat.

when you add `track by` you basically tell angular to generate a single DOM element per data object in the given collection

this could be useful when paging and filtering, or any case where objects are added or removed from `ng-repeat` list.

usually, without `track by` angular will link the DOM objects with the collection by injecting an expando property - `$$hashKey` - into your JavaScript objects, and will regenerate it (and re-associate a DOM object) with every change.

*full explanation:*

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

*a more practical guide:*

http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

(track by is available in angular > 1.2 )

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with objects **track by the identifier**(e.g. $index) instead of the whole object and you reload your data later, ngRepeat **will not rebuild the DOM elements** for items it has **already rendered**, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.

Comment: any reference that proves this?

Comment: is there a way to force re-rendering? or any other work around? i have not found this mentioned anywhere but i believe this is what creating a mess for me and i already wasted a lot of time.

Comment: either don't use track by or change the unique identifier on changing object. Note you cant change $index, its recommended not to use $index instead use identifier  unique to object (e.g. id)