# AngularJS: what is the usage of track by with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular and i go through this doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat but do not understand the objective of track by clause using with ng-option.

### here are few usage

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by myTrackingFunction(n)">
  {{n}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="model in collection track by model.id">
  {{model.name}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="obj in collection track by $id(obj)">
  {{obj.prop}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
    {{model.name}}
</div>
```

track by is something close to order by clause in sql ?

if yes then how can i specify sort order like **ASC or DESC ?**

in last **code track by and orderBy both use**....what they are doing. not clear what kind of output will come.

what is difference between **orderBy & track by ?**

**orderBy** is filter that i know. so track by is also a filter.

i know i am asking very basic question. basically posting here because things is not clear after reading it from doc. looking for some help and example to understand what track by does ?

how `track by` is different from `orderby` in terms of usage ?

Comment: Read the [ngRepeat official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in the Tracking and Duplicates section.

Comment: http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default orderBy will be in ascending order. You can use "reverse" for descending order like

In HTML Template Binding

{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}

In JavaScript

$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)

If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

For example, you may track items by the index of each item in the collection, using the special scope property $index:

```
`<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">

 {{n}}

</div>`
```

Comment: can you see mu posted code and help me to understand the meaning of 4th and 5th set of code.

Comment: In model object if your id property is unique and may be name property is duplicated go for this scenario    <div ng-repeat="model in collection track by model.id">
  {{model.name}}
</div>

Comment: If in "obj" object no property is unique then go for <div ng-repeat="obj in collection track by $id(obj)">
  {{obj.prop}}
</div>

Comment: If you want to track by id property and order by id property then go for <div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
    {{model.name}}
</div>     It will first sort in ascending order then it will do the track

Comment: For more clear info go for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761340/angularjs-ng-repeats-track-by-expression

Answer (score 2):

ngRepeat uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements

If a new item is added to the collection, ngRepeat will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.

[See the detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

If you have object for ngRepeat and it have any identity field (Like primary key value or Unique value), use it in track by.

Good thing is that if you are re-loading the list, dome will not re-render for existing items but only the new ones.

Comment: show me a example by which i can understand what  track by does with ng-repeat.

Comment: i have already visited the link you provided but not clear what track by does or orderby does ?

Comment: You already have examples in your question, suppose you are adding one more value 60 (in your first example), then angular will not render rest of the item because it is already there, It will add only one more 60.

Comment: Read before reply anyone or anything, hard to convince you.