# Simple angular select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't get angular to display the contents of an array object.

**Controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var items = [
            { id: 1, name: 'first obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } },
            { id: 2, name: 'second obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Loco-l' } },
            { id: 3, name: 'third obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } }           
  ];
  console.log(items)
});
```

**template.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="eachItem" ng-options="item for item in myCtrl.items">
    <option value="">My default value</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/reala/n5bg060t/4/

**EDIT:** I would like to display `item.type.name` , so two select fields will display "Global" then I'll eventually filter the results to show only unique values.

Comment: Your items are not defined in the `$scope`

Comment: What names and values do you want to actually use in your `<select>` widget?

Comment: you are mixing two definition styles here, but you haven't defined `items` in either.  You have `$scope`, but aren't using it, and you are trying to use `myCtrl.items` but you aren't defining `myCtrl` (ControllerAs) nor are you making `items` a property of `myCtrl`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would like to display the `item.type.name` , please see updated post.

Comment: after you fix the issues with your variable declarations, you are going to need to re-think your dropdown.  You can't populate the dropdown from the sub-items, you would end up with 3 rows for only 2 options.  if you want to make an option list that filters this array, you should make a separate array of the possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your items in your `$scope` and change the [`ng-option`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for display name like this:

```
ng-options="item as item.type.name for item in items track by item.id"
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n5bg060t/9/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
                { id: 1, name: 'name of first object', type: { isImp: true, name: 'Global' } },
                { id: 2, name: 'another alias of two', type: { isImp: true, name: 'Loco-l' } },
                { id: 3, name: 'another alias of two', type: { isImp: true, name: 'Global' } }           
  ];
  console.log($scope.items)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="eachItem" ng-options="item as item.type.name for item in items track by item.id">
    <option value="">My default value</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Selecting this as the best answer as it corrects my wasteful use of `$scope` and may provide more context for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5bg060t/8/) .Use `ng-options="item.type.name for item in items"` to display corectly options in select and must use $scope.items insteed items.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="eachItem" ng-options="item.type.name for item in items">
    <option value="">My default value</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I wrong in believing this ng-options syntax makes the most sense?

Comment: You can use  'track by $index' if your data source has duplicate identifiers.In this case there is no need.

Comment: Here you can understand more here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761340/understanding-the-ngrepeat-track-by-expression

Comment: But,as I said, in your case is no need.Good luck !.

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
            { id: 1, name: 'first obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } },
            { id: 2, name: 'second obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Loco-l' } },
            { id: 3, name: 'third obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } }           
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="item.selected">
    <option value="">My default value</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see this "as for in track by" syntax used a lot, and it really confuses me. The fact that its used so much, I'm going to assume its entirely my lack of understanding. However, this solution works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should try...

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="eachItem" ng-options="item as item.type.name for item in myCtrl.items track by item.id">
    <option value="">My default value</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var myCtrl= this;
        myCtrl.items = [
                    { id: 1, name: 'first obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } },
                    { id: 2, name: 'second obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Loco-l' } },
                    { id: 3, name: 'third obj', type: { open: true, name: 'Global' } }           
          ];
});
```

Comment: This looks like it makes sense to me - and really the approach I would prefer to take. However, I can't get this working when I store `myCtrl` in a variable and set it to `this`, then use `myCtrl.items` and attempt to access it inside ngOptions with `myCtrl.items`

Comment: yu need to use the controller as syntax... it's best not to put it in html but I did for this example

Comment: @bruh I updated the answer so it would work for you using the way you reference your ngcontroller in your html.