# Unique id for two ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to affect a unique Id to a div located inside two ng-repeat directives? See bellow example:

```
<!--data: [[{id: 'A'},{id: 'B'},{id: 'C'}], [{id: 'X'},{id: 'Y'}]]-->
<div ng-repeat = "item in data">
     <div ng-repeat = "sub-item in item">
        <div id = "{{$index}}">
     </div>
</div>
```

expected output:

```
<!--first ng-repeat-->
<div id = "1">
<div id = "2">
<div id = "3">
<div id = "4"> <!--start second array-->
<div id = "5">
```

Not:

```
<div id = "1">
<div id = "2">
<div id = "3">
<div id = "1"> <!--start second array-->
<div id = "2">
```

Update: I don't think track by or $parent.$index will work for this use case, obviously we have to calculate the length of each sub-array in order to get exact incremented counter. I'm currently trying a combination of two ng-init. I will update the post once I get something working

Comment: You can try using track by : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761340/understanding-the-ngrepeat-track-by-expression

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. What have you tired?

Comment: @1252748 I have tried combinations of $parent.$index and ng-init inside both ng-repeat so I can get exact counter but with no luck, check the post

Comment: Why do these elements need unique IDs?

Comment: It's actually for a d-pad remote control system for the Samsung tv tizen sdk, each division has to be identified by a unique ID (it's an ionic app)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to merge the 2 arrays?

Comment: @Erevald Yes, each sub-array have its own date, so the display has to be sorted by data like: event1 & event2 inside January cardbox, and event3 & event4 inside April cardbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work, here is my attempt:

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in data" ng-init = "count = 0">
 <div ng-repeat = "sub-item in item" ng-init="count = count + data[$parent.$index -1].length">
    <div id = "{{count+$index+1}}">
 </div>
```

Feel free to edit if you have a more suitable solution