# Duplicate cards created using dnd-draggable ,how to fix that?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I have a dashboard with fix size of cards(4).Whenever i shift any one card to another position, Duplicate of that same card got created in dashboard.
Now I have total 5 cards.If I do this same, again it will create duplicates.My aim is just to move a card to another position without duplication.

In **html file**

```
  <div class="card" 
        ng-repeat="card in dashCtrl.cards track by $index"
         dnd-draggable="card" 
         dnd-type="'card'" 
         dnd-effect-allowed="move"
         dnd-moved="dashCtrl.updateCardPosition($index)"
         dnd-dynamic-placeholder-size="true" ng-include="'/partials/dashboard/'+card.template+'.html'">
  </div>
```

Here dashCtrl == dashboard_controller

in **dashboard controller.**

```
function updateCardPosition($index) {
            // if(vm.cards.length!=4)validEntry();
            // vm.cards.splice($index, 1);
            console.log('dsdsdsdsds',$index);

            vm.cards = _.uniqBy(vm.cards,'template');
            vm.cards.forEach((ele)=>{
                console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',ele);  
            });
            // console.log("cards",vm.cards.length);
            // console.log('index',$index);
            Store.set('cards', JSON.stringify(vm.cards));
        }
```

Here  **vm** is object(**this**) of controller and it has many method.
So **vm.cards** is an array of **cards**.I used **Store**(for local storage)
to store modified array(in terms of position).

structure of vm.cards

```
vm.cards = [
            {template: 'agenda-card'},
            {template: 'budget-card'},
            {template: 'collaborate-card'},
            {template: 'todo-card'}
        ];
```

I checked everything from google but I couldn't find the solution.I guess duplication problem might arise from **dnd-draggable**.I am just guessing.
So how to solve that duplication problem??

Answer (score 0):

remove the `track by $index` from `ng-repeat="card in dashCtrl.cards track by $index"`

Comment: Please explain why removing `track by` is a solution. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22761548/4906586), if you have duplicate values when using `track by`, it means that your source list has duplicate values somewhere so removing `track by` won't remove the root cause of the issue